# How to define an Intersection in list-attribute of planning variable as Optaplanner Constraint?

Tags: java, optaplanner

I got started on Optaplanner and wanted to extend their example of a timetabling problem using [Maven/Spring Boot](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.41.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#useWithMavenGradleEtc) - now I would like to have multiple student groups that are supposed to attend specific courses - I have those saved in my planning Variable as `List<StudentGroupFact> studentGroupFacts` (see below).

I am assigning Lectures to Slots and Rooms, with slots being a unique combination of day/hour basically. (See my Planning Entity `LecturePlanning` below)

Now I'd formulate the following Constraint in my ConstraintProvider:

```
    private Constraint studentGroupConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(LecturePlanning.class)
            .join(LecturePlanning.class,
                    Joiners.equal(LecturePlanning::getLectureSlot),
                    Joiners.equal(LecturePlanning::getAssignedStudentGroups),
                    Joiners.greaterThan(LecturePlanning::getLectureID))
            .penalize("Student Group Conflict", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
    }
```

It is supposed to compare my `LecturePlanning`-objects (basically lectures) to penalize if a lecture is assigned for a slot which would lead to a `StudentGroup` (of my `AssignedStudentGroups`-list) would need to visit two courses at the same slot.

This of course would fail if there is an intersection in the `AssignedStudentGroups` list but they are not equal - sadly I did not figure out a way to solve this and I haven't seen anything like that mentioned in the tutorial - can someone help me out on this?

The planning entity:

```
    @PlanningEntity
    public class LecturePlanning {
    
        private int lectureID;
        private String lectureName;
        private int requiredRoomType;
        private int numberOfRoomsParallel;
        private boolean onlyTutors;
        private List<LecturerFact> lecturerFacts;
        private List<StudentGroupFact> assignedStudentGroups;
    
        @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "lectureSlotRange")
        private LectureSlotFact lectureSlot;
    
        @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "roomRange")
        private RoomFact room;

        //..

      }


The Constraint Provider class (currently full impl. - includes the snippet at the beginning of this post):

public class ScheduleConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[] {
                roomConflict(constraintFactory),
                teacherConflict(constraintFactory),
                studentGroupConflict(constraintFactory)
        };
    }

    private Constraint roomConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.from(LecturePlanning.class)
                .join(LecturePlanning.class,
                        Joiners.equal(LecturePlanning::getLectureSlot),
                        Joiners.equal(LecturePlanning::getRoom),
                        Joiners.greaterThan(LecturePlanning::getLectureID))
                .penalize("Room Conflict", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
    }

    private Constraint teacherConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.from(LecturePlanning.class)
                .join(LecturePlanning.class,
                        Joiners.equal(LecturePlanning::getLectureSlot),
                        Joiners.equal(LecturePlanning::getLecturerFacts),
                        Joiners.greaterThan(LecturePlanning::getLectureID))
                .penalize("Lecturer Conflict", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
    }

    private Constraint studentGroupConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.from(LecturePlanning.class)
                .join(LecturePlanning.class,
                        Joiners.equal(LecturePlanning::getLectureSlot),
                        Joiners.equal(LecturePlanning::getAssignedStudentGroups),
                        Joiners.greaterThan(LecturePlanning::getLectureID))
                .penalize("Student Group Conflict", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, plz have a look at the "other functions" of [Joiners](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.27.0.Final/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/score/stream/Joiners.html) ..besides `equal(..)` there are many other functions, which could address your problem (containig, disjoin, *intersecting* (?), ...)

Comment: @xerx593 Thanks for the hint, sadly I cannot access these functions (`Containing`, `Intersecting`) from the code (e.g. `Joiners.intersecting` is unknown instead of `Joiners.equal`), yet `greaterThan` or `LessThan` are available. Anyway I am having troubles understanding the documentation in regards to any requirements to using those functions that may exist

Comment: You should be able to do that with a `Joiners.filtering((lecture1, lecture2) -> !intersect(lecture1, lecture2)`, where `interesect()` is a function you implement yourself. One caveat: this will not perform well, since going through those collections on every single pair will hurt. I suggest you come up with a way to cache this information.

I'm not sure where the containing/disjoint/intersecting joiner suggestion above comes from, since we have not implemented these joiners yet and have no immediate plans.